# Add a new line (\n) in front of every forward arrow (>)

Tags: linux, sed, bioinformatics

I have `file1.fa` in the format as below:

```
>XXX[YY]
ZZZZZZ>XXX[YY]
ZZZZZZ>XXX[YY]
ZZZZZZ
```

I was trying to add a new lines before the forward arrow using sed command but it doesn't work.

```
sed 's/ \?\>/ \n\>/g' file1.fa > file2.fa
```

The desired file format:

```
>XXX[YY]
ZZZZZZ
>XXX[YY]
ZZZZZZ
>XXX[YY]
ZZZZZZ
```

I have tried it with other characters and the script working just fine.

I wonder if there happened to be any restriction that I have to include when dealing with the forward arrow in sed? Or anybody know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not escape `>` (`\>` is a special *word-boundary* pattern).

This is working for me (using GNU `sed`):

```
 sed -e 's/>/\n>/g' file1
```

For your case the output which I am getting is:

```
>XXX[YY]
ZZZZZZ
>XXX[YY]
ZZZZZZ
>XXX[YY]
ZZZZZZ
```

Comment: I made some error in typing my script earlier (already updated). Btw your script is working here as well, thanks!

Comment: @Kusalananda thanks for clarifying about \> !

Answer (score 1):

The `\>` is a special pattern that will match the zero-width space between a word and non-word character.  The `>` is not special in any sense, so it does not need to be escaped.

To add a newline before each `>` on each line except the first, using standard `sed`, you may do

```
$ sed '2,${ y/>/\n/;s/\n/&>/g; }' file
>XXX[YY]
ZZZZZZ
>XXX[YY]
ZZZZZZ
>XXX[YY]
ZZZZZZ
```

Standard `sed` can't insert a newline with `s/>/\n>/g`, so we have to do it in two steps.

The `2,$` addresses all lines in the input except for the initial line. The commands within `{ ... }` will be applied to these lines.

The `y/>/\n/` command is replacing all instances of the character `>` with a newline.  The `y` command *can* insert newlines in standard `sed`.

The `s/\n/&>/g` replaces each generated newline with the matched newline followed by `>`.  When `&` occurs in the replacement part of a `s` command, it inserts whatever the pattern matched.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with below method and it worked fine

command:  `sed "/^[^>]/s/>.*/\n&/g" filename`

output

```
sed "/^[^>]/s/>.*/\n&/g" filename
>XXX[YY]
ZZZZZZ
>XXX[YY]
ZZZZZZ
>XXX[YY]
ZZZZZZ
```